# Error running flutter project using Firebase Database

Tags: firebase, flutter

I've been having this issue after adding `firebase_database: ^7.0.0-dev.2` to my project. I've also looked at other issues on GitHub, here on S/O, and on the Flutter repo but to no success.

Some of the troubleshooting attempts I have tried include:

1. deleting the `pod` files, `Podfile`, `Podfile.lock`, etc.
2. running `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get`
3. running `pod install`

I've created a new flutter project and added `firebase_core: ^1.1.0` and `firebase_database: ^7.0.0-dev.2` to the `pubspec.yaml`. Therefore, I know the issue is not because of dependency conflicts with other flutter packages in my project.

Here is the output from the debug log when I try to run it on a simulator:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (2nd generation) in debug mode...
Running pod install...                                           1,832ms
Running Xcode build...                                                  
Xcode build done.                                            3.4s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    objc[4399]: Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both ?? (0x1f1f7c188) and ?? (0x117eb02b8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[4399]: Class AMSupportURLSession is implemented in both ?? (0x1f1f7c1d8) and ?? (0x117eb0308). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    ** BUILD FAILED **

Xcode's output:
↳
    /Users/hetpatel/Documents/MobileApps/FlutterProjects/flutter_application_1/ios/Pods/FirebaseDatabase/FirebaseDatabase/Sources/Realtime/FWebSocketConnection.m:22:9: fatal error:
    'FirebaseCore/Sources/Private/FirebaseCoreInternal.h' file not found
    #import "FirebaseCore/Sources/Private/FirebaseCoreInternal.h"
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Users/hetpatel/Documents/MobileApps/FlutterProjects/flutter_application_1/ios/Pods/FirebaseDatabase/FirebaseDatabase/Sources/Realtime/FWebSocketConnection.m:22:9: note: did not find header
    'Sources/Private/FirebaseCoreInternal.h' in framework 'FirebaseCore' (loaded from '/Users/hetpatel/Documents/MobileApps/FlutterProjects/flutter_application_1/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseCore')
    1 error generated.
    In file included from /Users/hetpatel/Documents/MobileApps/FlutterProjects/flutter_application_1/ios/Pods/FirebaseDatabase/FirebaseDatabase/Sources/Core/View/FView.m:18:
    In file included from /Users/hetpatel/Documents/MobileApps/FlutterProjects/flutter_application_1/ios/Pods/FirebaseDatabase/FirebaseDatabase/Sources/Api/Private/FIRDatabaseQuery_Private.h:19:
    In file included from /Users/hetpatel/Documents/MobileApps/FlutterProjects/flutter_application_1/ios/Pods/FirebaseDatabase/FirebaseDatabase/Sources/Core/FRepo.h:17:
    In file included from /Users/hetpatel/Documents/MobileApps/FlutterProjects/flutter_application_1/ios/Pods/FirebaseDatabase/FirebaseDatabase/Sources/Core/FPersistentConnection.h:19:
    In file included from /Users/hetpatel/Documents/MobileApps/FlutterProjects/flutter_application_1/ios/Pods/FirebaseDatabase/FirebaseDatabase/Sources/Realtime/FConnection.h:17:
    In file included from /Users/hetpatel/Documents/MobileApps/FlutterProjects/flutter_application_1/ios/Pods/FirebaseDatabase/FirebaseDatabase/Sources/Realtime/FWebSocketConnection.h:17:
    /Users/hetpatel/Documents/MobileApps/FlutterProjects/flutter_application_1/ios/Pods/FirebaseDatabase/FirebaseDatabase/Sources/Utilities/FUtilities.h:17:9: fatal error: 'FirebaseCore/Sources/Private/FirebaseCoreInternal.h'
    file not found
    #import "FirebaseCore/Sources/Private/FirebaseCoreInternal.h"
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Users/hetpatel/Documents/MobileApps/FlutterProjects/flutter_application_1/ios/Pods/FirebaseDatabase/FirebaseDatabase/Sources/Utilities/FUtilities.h:17:9: note: did not find header 'Sources/Private/FirebaseCoreInternal.h'
    in framework 'FirebaseCore' (loaded from '/Users/hetpatel/Documents/MobileApps/FlutterProjects/flutter_application_1/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseCore')
    1 error generated.
    In file included from /Users/hetpatel/Documents/MobileApps/FlutterProjects/flutter_application_1/ios/Pods/FirebaseDatabase/FirebaseDatabase/Sources/FValueIndex.m:21:
    /Users/hetpatel/Documents/MobileApps/FlutterProjects/flutter_application_1/ios/Pods/FirebaseDatabase/FirebaseDatabase/Sources/Utilities/FUtilities.h:17:9: fatal error: 'FirebaseCore/Sources/Private/FirebaseCoreInternal.h'
    file not found
    #import "FirebaseCore/Sources/Private/FirebaseCoreInternal.h"
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Users/hetpatel/Documents/MobileApps/FlutterProjects/flutter_application_1/ios/Pods/FirebaseDatabase/FirebaseDatabase/Sources/Utilities/FUtilities.h:17:9: note: did not find header 'Sources/Private/FirebaseCoreInternal.h'
    in framework 'FirebaseCore' (loaded from '/Users/hetpatel/Documents/MobileApps/FlutterProjects/flutter_application_1/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseCore')
    1 error generated.
    /Users/hetpatel/Documents/MobileApps/FlutterProjects/flutter_application_1/ios/Pods/FirebaseDatabase/FirebaseDatabase/Sources/Core/View/FValueEventRegistration.m:18:9: fatal error:
    'FirebaseCore/Sources/Private/FirebaseCoreInternal.h' file not found
    #import "FirebaseCore/Sources/Private/FirebaseCoreInternal.h"
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Users/hetpatel/Documents/MobileApps/FlutterProjects/flutter_application_1/ios/Pods/FirebaseDatabase/FirebaseDatabase/Sources/Core/View/FValueEventRegistration.m:18:9: note: did not find header
    'Sources/Private/FirebaseCoreInternal.h' in framework 'FirebaseCore' (loaded from '/Users/hetpatel/Documents/MobileApps/FlutterProjects/flutter_application_1/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseCore')
    1 error generated.
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Analyzing workspace
    note: Constructing build description
    note: Build preparation complete
    /Users/hetpatel/Documents/MobileApps/FlutterProjects/flutter_application_1/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported
    deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'leveldb-library' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/hetpatel/Documents/MobileApps/FlutterProjects/flutter_application_1/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported
    deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'Flutter' from project 'Pods')

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (2nd generation).
```

Comment: have you tried to increase your deployment target ?

Comment: Yes, I read on the documentation to increase it to version 10.

Comment: increased it in every where ? even in pod ?

Comment: Yes, in the Runner target and also in the Pods target. Did this through XCode.

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround for now:

dropped `firebase_core` to version `"0.7.0"` and `firebase_database` to `^6.0.0`